# file_regex breaks sublime build

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-build

This regex works in the SublimeText search field:

```
([^\/]+\.java)
```

If I use that regex in a `.sublime-build` file:

- `\.` is highlighted in red, and
- the build system is not recognised.

When I comment out the line `"file_regex": "([^\/]+\.java)"` the build system is recognised.

```
{
  "cmd": ["gradle" , "build"],
  "working_dir": "${project_path}",
  "file_regex": "([^\/]+\.java)"
}
```

**Question:** Why does the regex that works in search not work in the `.sublime-build` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.sublime-build` file uses the JSON file format.

You need to escape your backslash for JSON to handle it and pass the backslash on to regex.

Like this:

```
"file_regex": "([^\/]+\\.java)"
```

Since the build system is going to be used in the Python underlying Sublime Text let's reassure ourselves that Python is going to read this as we expect.

**Test Python code:**

```
import re

builddict = {
  "cmd": ["gradle" , "build"],
  "working_dir": "${project_path}",
  "file_regex": "([^\/]+\\.java)"
}

re_pattern = builddict['file_regex']
prog = re.compile(re_pattern)

teststrings = ['aaa.java', 'aaajava']

for teststring in teststrings:
    result = prog.search(teststring)

    if result is None:
        print(teststring + ' no match')
    else:
        print(teststring + ' matched')
```

**Output:**

```
aaa.java matched
aaajava no match
```

I assume that meets your desired output?